# Service in Application class doing web socket connection crashes

Tags: android, service, java-websocket

I'm building a chat application, which uses web socket. I've wrote a service, which is called in Application class. The problem is that, sometimes the mConnection becomes null when I just start the app after the crash. I think that it's because of the service being run on the background even when I quit the app, and when i start it again, it can't create the new service and bind to it. 
My questions are: Is it a good way of writing the code? And is there a way to stop the service on the application destroy?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
  private final AtomicInteger refCount = new AtomicInteger();
    public ConnectionService mConnectionService;
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            ConnectionService.MyBinder b = (ConnectionService.MyBinder) binder;
            mConnectionService = b.getService();
            Log.d("MyApplication", "MyApplication has been bounded");
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mConnectionService = null;
            Log.d("MyApplication", "MyApplication has been unbounded");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class);
        getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public ConnectionService getConnectionService() {
        refCount.incrementAndGet();
        Log.d("MyApplication", "getConnectionService, current: "+refCount);
        return mConnectionService;
    }

    public void releaseConnectionService() {

        if (refCount.get() == 0 || refCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            mConnectionService.stopSelf();
            Log.d("MyApplication", "MyApplication has been stopped ");
        }
        Log.d("MyApplication", "releaseConnectionService, current: "+refCount);
    }
```

}

And the another class looks something like this:

```
    public class LobbyActivity extends Activity{
    ListView lvContacts;
    Gson gson;
    LoginData mLoginData;
    MyReceiver receiver;
    ArrayList<User> users;
    LobbyAdapter lobbyAdapter;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gson = new Gson();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String loginDataJson = intent.getStringExtra("LoginData");
    mLoginData = gson.fromJson(loginDataJson, LoginData.class);
    getActionBar().setTitle(mLoginData.getUsername());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lobby);    
    users = new ArrayList<User>();

    lvContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
    lobbyAdapter=new LobbyAdapter(users, this);
    lvContacts.setAdapter(lobbyAdapter);

    Commands cmd = new Commands(getApplicationContext());
    cmd.sendCommand(Commands.COMMAND_GET_MANAGER_LIST);
    cmd.sendCommand(Commands.COMMAND_GET_USER_LIST);

    receiver = new MyReceiver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectionService.MESSAGE);
            String notification = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectionService.NOTIFICATION);
            if (message!=null){
                try {
                    switch (Utils.getCommand(message)) {
                    case Commands.COMMAND_GET_USER_LIST:
                        ArrayList<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
                        user  = (gson.fromJson(message, UserList.class)).users;
                        users.addAll(user);
                        lobbyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION));

}
    class UserList{
        String cmd;
        ArrayList<User> users; 
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).releaseConnectionService();
    }

}
```

The reason why i put the service in the Application class is that i want it to be up as long as the application runs; and also it is needed to be accessed by all the activities.

Comment: how can it be null if the only place when you are setting it is: mConnection = new ServiceConnection () {... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good way of writing the code?

I would say that it's not a good programming practice to start Android app components like `Service` or `Activity` from `Application` class. You should start Service from `Activity` or `BroadcastReceiver` component. In the end code inside `Application onCreate` runs because the new process is created for your application when it starts. This happen if you start app from launcher and main `Activity` starts or `BroadcastReceiver` has been given a call. At this moment you can start `Service` from either of them.

> And is there a way to stop the service on the application destroy?

You can stop `Service` from Activity's `onDestroy()`. If you don't want to stop Service on every configuration change (like screen rotation) you can check in `onDestory` method whether it is destroying or only reloading through `isChangingConfigurations` method of `Activity` and decide to stop or not `Service` basing on that knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it is almost what i needed, but before I mark it as correct, please, give me some more advices. The reason why i put it into the Application class is that i need it to be global: like i want this service always to support the web socket connection while the app is up. And i want to use it's methods (like "sendMessage" to be accessed by other activities. Please,  tell me how should i architect my app. Gonna be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What if i make the service static?

Comment: As you may know `Service` in Android OS can essentially take two forms: started and bounded. Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed. A bound service offers a client-server interface that allows components to interact with the service, send requests and get results. So start your `Service` in the main `Activity`. Then bound to `Service` from every `Activity` that would like to communicate with it and unbound when particular `Activity` is being destoyed. Stop your service when you will be leaving your app.

Comment: I don't want to bother you, but can you also vote up the answer?

Comment: Sure =) sorry for that. I'm still new here